# How to process the output data fromTax4fun, a R program for predicting functional profiles from metagenomic 16S rRNA data?

Tags: r

I'm learning to use Tax4Fun (http://tax4fun.gobics.de/) now, but I have some questions. I have got the Tax4FunProfiles, e.g. K00001; alcohol dehydrogenase [EC:1.1.1.1].....(there are more than 10000 reads in the file), and what  I can do with the output file in the downstream analysis, might do some connection to KEEG?

Comment: The R commands are below. 
   pathReferenceData <- "C:/R/tax4fun/SILVA123/"
  file <- "otu_table_ck.txt"
  QIIMESingleData <- importQIIMEData(file)
  Tax4FunOutput <- Tax4Fun(QIIMESingleData,pathReferenceData,TRUE,"UProC",TRUE,TRUE)
  print(Tax4FunOutput)


Tax4FunProfile <- Tax4FunOutput$Tax4FunProfile
Tax4FunProfile <- data.frame(t(Tax4FunOutput$Tax4FunProfile))
View(Tax4FunProfile)
#save to excel 
write.table(Tax4FunProfile,"Tax4FunProfile_Export.csv",sep="\t")

Comment: please add that code formatted to the question and not in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that your answer depends on your research question, right? Why do you want to do a functional profiling of your prokaryotic community and what are you looking for?

Based on your code in the comment you save the KO abundance table as a tab separated file.

You could use this file to analyse your metagenomic profile with [STAMP](https://picrust.github.io/picrust/tutorials/stamp_tutorial.html) or find "biomarker" KO's using [LEfSe](https://twbattaglia.gitbooks.io/introduction-to-qiime/content/lefse.html).

In addition, I think that your gene table contains more than 6000 KOs. You can also predict pathways with TAX4FUN:

```
KEGG_pathways <- Tax4Fun(df, fctProfiling = FALSE, refProfile = "UProC", shortReadMode = FALSE, normCopyNo = TRUE, folderReferenceData = "~/work/tax4fun_files/R_ressources/SILVA123")
```

This would result in ~300 metabolic pathways instead of >6000 KOs. In theory you could also use your KO table with [HUMANN](https://huttenhower.sph.harvard.edu/humann) or [HUMANN2](http://huttenhower.sph.harvard.edu/humann2) to create metabolic pathways.